# Estimate using the Linear Approximation and find the error using a calculator: 12^(1/3) − 2.

Tags: calculus

I am unable to find delta X in this question.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. What formula are you using? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they ask for a linear approximation (I don't think it should say "the" linear approximation, there are many) I would think of a tangent line and so take the derivative.  Here, I would take $y= x^{1/3}- 2$.  The derivative is $y'= \frac{x^{-2/3}}{3}$.  The closest point to x= 12 where that derivative has a simple value is x= 8.  At x= 8, $y'= \frac{8^{-2/3}}{3}= \frac{2^{-2}}{3}= \frac{1}{12}$.  Also $y(8)= 8^{1/3}- 2= 2- 2= 0$.  The tangent line to $y= x^{1/3}- 2$ at x= 8 is $y= \frac{1}{12}(x- 8)$.  At x= 12, $y= \frac{1}{12}(12- 8)= \frac{4}{12}= \frac{1}{3}$.

Since you are allowed to use a calculator to find the error just calculate $12^{1/3}-2$.  The calculator included with Windows gives $12^{1/3}- 2= 2.2894284661432769246344393563094- 2= 0.28942846614327692463443935630943.  The difference between 1/3 and that is 0.04390486719005640869889397702391, the "error".